# Janela de imprimir, salvar PDF Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Após desenvolver uma página web, estou desenvolvendo o teste automatizado desta. Estou utilizando Selenium WebDriver com para .NET.

Após clicar no botão imprimir, o popup para escolher a impressora ou mudar para PDF é exibido, com isso meu teste para, ele volta a executar logo após imprimir/salvar o documento ou cancelar a operação. Existe alguma maneira de manipular este popup/window.

Me refiro a este popup/window:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A tela de preview de impressão está fora dos limites do selenium, então apenas com ele creio que não será possível, uma alternativa é combinar a utilização com alguma ferramenta como o Sikuli ou Autoit que não se delimitam apenas ao browser.

Comment: Obrigado @LucasMiranda!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para janelas do Windows ou windows form, você precisa usar outro Framework como o [UIAutomationClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/uiauto-clientportal),

veja o exemplos abaixo.

```
var processoId = Process.GetProcessesByName(Nome do processo).First().Id;               
AutomationElement rootElement  = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, processId));

var botaoSalva = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Nome da propriedade do botão salva"));

object obj;

if (botaoSalva.TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out obj))
{
    InvokePattern invoker = obj as InvokePattern;

    invoker.Invoke();
}
```

Existe ferramentas como o **inspect** e o **UIAVerify** que permite ver as propriedade de cada campo da janela para obter o nome das propriedade.

Answer (score -4):

Ola, sou iniciante do iniciante no mundo do python, criei um projeto para aceitar pedidos automaticamente e tinha o mesmo problema, no meu caso, resolvi com a opção --kiosk-printing, essa opção faz o chrome imprimir sem exibir a janela de visualização de impressão. . Refiz a resposta, só tinha avaliação de nao util. Espero que te ajude.

Exemplo:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    options.add_argument("--kiosk-printing") #fecha a janela de impressão
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get('minha_pagina_de_pedido')

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    imprimir_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="print-button"]')))

    imprimir_button.click()
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).